# Автопрокрутка слайдов при использовании fullPage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage

С помощью данного скрипта

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({   
    anchors: ['home', 'about', 'contact'],
    afterRender: function () {
        setInterval(function () {
            $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideRight();
        }, 2000); // каждые 2 секунды крутим вправо
    }
});
```

я реализовываю автоматическую прокрутку горизонтального слайдера. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kixkix/th6cfw7o/). Проблема заключается в том, что дойдя до последнего слайда, слайдер прокручивается к первому справа-налево через все промежуточные. Как сделать так, чтобы от последнего слайда к первому прокрутка оставалась слева-направо?

Например для вертикальной прокрутки это уже предусмотрено, указав в настройках 
`continuousVertical: true` [получим следующий результат](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/continuous.html).

Answer (score 1):

исходя из логики вам нужно добавить    continuousGorizontal: true

```js
$('#fullpage').fullpage({   
        anchors: ['home', 'about', 'contact'],
    continuousGorizontal: true,
        afterRender: function () {
            setInterval(function () {
                $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideRight();
            }, 2000);
        }
});
```

Comment: такая опция, к сожалению, не предусмотрена автором